# Extract text from PCL6 using Java

Tags: java, printer-control-language

I don't have much knowledge regarding PCL6 file format. I wanted to know if there is any way to extract text out of PCL6 file using Java.

Thanks,
Usman

Comment: Did you find anything to do this. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file to PDF (see [Ghostscript/GhostPDL](http://www.ghostscript.com/GhostPCL.html)) and then use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/).

The first step will require to use some Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)